# Extracting indexing wise elements

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = {'fid':['EL202AK5130C','EL531BC3090K','EL617BE2110PA','EL614A36120G','EL607AJ3200MA'],'testdate':['2021-07-01 00:07:02','2021-07-01 00:07:20',
                                                                                                        '2021-07-01 00:07:48','2021-07-01 00:08:16','2021-07-01 00:08:23'],
       'failrea':['HA13','ST13','MFD','NOTRACE','HA15']}

df = Dataframe(data)

    fid testdate    failrea
0   EL202AK5130C    2021-07-01 00:07:02 HA13
1   EL531BC3090K    2021-07-01 00:07:20 ST13
2   EL617BE2110PA   2021-07-01 00:07:48 MFD
3   EL614A36120G    2021-07-01 00:08:16 NOTRACE
4   EL607AJ3200MA   2021-07-01 00:08:23 HA15
```

But I want to create another column with rows like:

```
preid
EL202AK513
EL531BC3090
EL617BE2110
EL614A36120
EL607AJ3200
```

Please can any one suggest how to do this?

Comment: Explain how you arrived at the expected output. @vikram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the regex approach

```
df['preid'] = df.fid.str.extract('(\w+\d)\w+$')
```

OR

To extract elements using just index

```
df['preid'] = df.fid.str[:11]
```

Comment: Extracting elements from 1st to 11th position from fid column

Comment: Updated Answer @vikram. If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).